# In Ruby, why Time.parse() isn't defined but Time.now() is?

Tags: ruby

I think to use Time.parse(), it needs to have a

```
require 'time'
```

but why `Time.now` is usable but `Time.parse` is not?

Comment: `Time.parse()` is in the [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html) class, `Time.now` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the 'time' library extends the Time class (see [time.rb](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/files/lib/time_rb.html)). Thus, 'parse' is defined and implemented in the library, where as 'now' is a class function).